# No "layout" folder in AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I've been following this(https://youtu.be/4M0hNugPJV8) YouTube tutorial on how to create projects in AndroidStudio and they go to **res/layout** folder to work with the **activity_main.xml** file

When creating a project i've chosen an Empty Activity, but can't see anything like **activity_main.xml** file here.
Is it possible to add it somehow? Can't figure out how do i work with it in the latest version of the AndroidStudio.
Thank You

[Here is the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1AL9.png)

Comment: You screenshot indicates you're using Compose which doesn't use XML layout files. But if you want to create one, just right-click `res/layout` and do `New > Layout Resource File`.

Answer (score 14):

While creating a new project, Choose `Empty Views Activity` instead of `Empty Activity`.

Things have been updated.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for the information. It seems that Studio has modified the `Empty Activity` because even the `MainActivity` file appears unusual. However, everything reverts back to the classic "Hello World" file with the `Empty Views Activity`.

Additionally, with the new `New Activity` format, you can add a `Layout` directory to the `app`. You can achieve this by going to `File -> New -> XML -> Layout XML` file. However, it's essential to right-click on 'app' first, or the `New -> XML` option will not appear. It will also prompt you for a file name.

For now, I think I'll stick with the `Empty Views Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-Click `res` folder
2. Go to `New`
3. Select `Android Resource File`
4. Type a file name. (e.g. layout_dummy)
5. Click `Resource Type` to get a drop-down menu.
6. Select `layout` and click `ok`.

You will be able to see `layout` directory again.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you've already resolved your issue but I encountered the same problem and found what I believe is the intended solution to this.
The tutorial said to create an "Empty Activity" project which creates the basic "Hello World" using Composable functions. Not too sure what those are yet, but I looked and found that you can create an "Empty Views Activity" instead and that creates the same project but includes the layout that the tutorial references.